# Are there tips or best practice for testing an application with different app servers?

Tags: java, tomcat, jboss, weblogic, websphere

I was testing an application for different app servers? Jboss, Websphere, Weblogic and tomcat.

Almost, I spent my time at installing configuring and unintalling the servers. It is poor efficiency. Do you know some tools or solutions to help me solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Virtualization using vmware or the like?

Comment: Is this an application you wrote and need it to possibly run on more than one of your clients' setups, or are you testing a third party app?

Comment: This is a web admin applications, but it has some features to configure app server, eg: log configuration.

Answer (score 2):

I wonder why would you want to do that. however, what you can do is write a selenium script and start up all the servers on different port. Your selenium script can do a good smoke testing on all the different servers.